# QR Code encoding using zxing to encode url data

Tags: java, qr-code, zxing, emv

I want to embed some raw text as well as a url inside a qr code.
for example data can be :
ABCD http://www.example.com XYZ
now on scanning http://www.example.com should be popped up and remaining data should be kept intact.
means i will encode (ABCD http://www.example.com XYZ) inside my qr code but i want (http://www.example.com) to be popped up.

I have tried it using zxing
but on scanning extire string gets displayed

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Define the data, including a properly formatted URL
    String data = "ABCD https://www.google.com fgh";

    // Define QR code properties
    int width = 300;
    int height = 300;
    String fileType = "png"; // or "jpg", "gif", etc.

    // Create hints for QR code generation
    Map<EncodeHintType, Object> hints = new HashMap<>();
    hints.put(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, "UTF-8");
    hints.put(EncodeHintType.MARGIN, 1);

    try {
        // Generate QR code
        QRCodeWriter qrCodeWriter = new QRCodeWriter();
        BitMatrix bitMatrix = qrCodeWriter.encode(data, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, width, height, hints);

        // Create a BufferedImage from the BitMatrix
        BufferedImage qrImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                qrImage.setRGB(x, y, bitMatrix.get(x, y) ? 0xFF000000 : 0xFFFFFFFF);
            }
        }

        // Save the QR code to a file
        File qrFile = new File("clickable_url_qrcode." + fileType);
        ImageIO.write(qrImage, fileType, qrFile);

        System.out.println("Clickable URL QR code generated successfully!");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error generating QR code: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Output:
ABCD https://www.google.com fgh
on scanning qr

I have to use this format
as because this is just an example but i am using emvco specification which is correctly specified
and there link is preceeded and succeeded by space

Comment: use 3 strings to concat `s1=ABCD` , `s2=url` , `s3 = xyz`  and the final string `sf = s1 + s2 + s3` .   for showing full string use `sf` , if you want use url only use `s2` .

Comment: @Elango, i wish to encode sf  to qr code 
but need to "POP -UP" on scanning only s2

Answer (score 0):

try this is

```
    //after scanning 
    String data = "ABCD https://www.google.com fgh";
    String[] urls = data.split("\\s+");

    for (String url : urls) {
      if (url.startsWith("http://") || url.startsWith("https://")) {
                System.out.println(url);
                //it will print "https://www.google.com";
            }
        }
```

Comment: thanks @Elango for your response,

this might print me the url
but i want the scanner like google lens or so to understand that https://www.google.com is a link  so to redirect to this and ignore other data like 
ABCD xyz

Comment: You can use `url` wherever you want (pop-up) , I just shown how to extract a URL from a scanned QR code without data like ABCD xyz. pls add it to qs, if you have any expected out image

Comment: no, i want to generate QR code with popped up url,